# Field validation partially working

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.Net MVC form that requires a "Name".

```
<input type="text" id="Name" value="" class="form-control" tabindex="1" placeholder="insert client name" name="Name" required/>
```

So, using Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE it wont let me submit without a name, great!

[image]

However I have noticed that my users are able (finding a way) to submit the form without the validation kicking in.

On my controller I even set a specific alert to let me know

```
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult New(ViewModels.Client client)
        {
...
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(client.Name))
            {
                throw new Exception("Client does not have a name ");
            }
}
```

What am I missing, how are users\browsers getting around this?

Comment: Are you validating if the input is space "    " ?

Comment: `required` is a HTML5 attribute and is not supported in older browsers which your users may be using. Instead, use MVC's built in client side validation. But you must always validate on the server anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is go into your ViewModels.Client class and add:

```
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Then you can add validations above the .Name attribute as follows:

```
    [Required()]
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Then inside your New Method you should have a check for ModelState.IsValid as in:

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      //Save the data
    }
```

Also meant to ask, are you performing the "Save" prior to raising the exception and could the user be submitting non-printable characters that just look like spaces?

Comment: I have the the following on the model [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = " required")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name:To Long")]

Comment: Are you checking ModelState.IsValid?  If you look at the data that was submitted, is the length=0?  If it is > 0 you analyze and see if the ASCII code is 32 (Space) or something else.  IsNullOrEmpty should handle no values as well as spaces in the string.

Comment: Also, one way a user could easily get by the client side validation is to use a proxy editor like BurpSuite or Fiddler.   They enter a value to pass validation and then capture the submission before it goes to the server and modify the response.  You'd have to be pretty savvy and I doubt users are purposely doing this, but that is a way around client side validation.  That is why you always want to check ModelState.IsValid on the server side because there are ways around.  Sounds like you have the DataAnnotations set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The client cannot disable the serverside validation. The only problem I can identify is that you only validate if the input in null or empty.

You should also check if the input is just blank spaces ("     "), i believe this is the issue.

Comment: I believe " " is covered in Validation, ive just checked on Safari and chrome and appears correct